# How do i give divs equal position power

Tags: javascript, html, css, formatting

My code was very confusing before I apologize. Allow me to make it simple and readable.
Basically what I want is that when any of the 4 divs is clicked it transitions to become full screen. And then when you click it again it closes/transitions right back to original position.
That works perfectly for div 4 but the first 3 divs are giving transition problems when CLOSING. In the case of the first div, when it closes there is no transition at all. 
I hope this is clear and any help would be appreciated.
Below is my simplified code.

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head>
                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <title>layout</title>
                <style>
                html, body 
                {
                   height: 100%; 
                   padding: 0; 
                   margin: 0;
                   font-family:'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
                   color:black;
                   font-size:300%;

                }

                #div1 
                { 
                    background-color:red;
                    position:absolute;
                    transition:0.3s;
                    top:0;
                    left:0;
                    width: 50%;
                      height: 50%;
                }

                #div2 
                { 
                     background-color:blue;
                     position:absolute;
                     top:0;
                     right:0;
                     transition:0.3s;
                     width: 50%;
                      height: 50%;
                }

                #div3
                { 
                     background-color:green;
                     position:absolute;
                     bottom:0;
                     left:0;
                     transition:0.3s;
                     width: 50%;
                      height: 50%;
                }

                #div4 
                { 
                   background-color:yellow;
                   position:absolute;
                   bottom:0;
                   right:0;
                   transition:0.3s;
                   width: 50%;
                      height: 50%;
                }


                #div1.fullscreen
                {
                    z-index: 9999; 
                    width: 100%; 
                    height: 100%; 
                    position: fixed; 
                    top: 0; 
                    left: 0; 
                }
                 #div2.fullscreen
                {
                    z-index: 9999; 
                    width: 100%; 
                    height: 100%; 
                    position: fixed; 
                    top: 0; 
                    right: 0; 
                }
                 #div3.fullscreen
                {
                    z-index: 9999; 
                    width: 100%; 
                    height: 100%; 
                    position: fixed; 
                    bottom: 0; 
                    left: 0; 
                }
                 #div4.fullscreen
                {
                    z-index: 9999; 
                    width: 100%; 
                    height: 100%; 
                    position: fixed; 
                    bottom: 0; 
                    right: 0; 
                }

                 </style>
            </head>
            <body>

                    <div id="div1">
                        div 1
                    </div>

                    <div id="div2">
                        div 2
                    </div>

                    <div id="div3">
                       div 3
                    </div>

                    <div id="div4">
                        div 4
                    </div>



                <script>
                    $('#div1').click(function (e) {
                        $('#div1').toggleClass('fullscreen');
                    });

                    $('#div2').click(function (e) {
                        $('#div2').toggleClass('fullscreen');
                    });

                    $('#div3').click(function (e) {
                        $('#div3').toggleClass('fullscreen');
                    });

                    $('#div4').click(function (e) {
                        $('#div4').toggleClass('fullscreen');
                    });
                </script>

            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: Nothing is full screen when I click on anything and the text is white so I can't see anything. Can you update your demo so it's easy to reproduce the behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Did not get it from your code preview, but let me to reduce your code a bit before. So, what do we get here. Your `#center` container is `z-index: 15;`, so it's always over other div's.

Even if we change it to `z-index: 0;` we have a problem: each of your div is inside inline element `a` and because div's a absolutely positioned they do not affect on parent `a` element size. Each `a` is 0px × 0px sized and located at the beginning of page.

`Float` parameters gives nothing for `absolute`'ly positioned elements, because `absolute` takes element out of elements flow. What should we do to make it work as you want?

First of all - make parent `a` element valuable: change property of `div {}` to `a {}`.

[image]

Second one, I have a question, why does we have sure in the size of div's inner content and background size: change `background-size: 100% 100%;` to `background-size: cover;` to fulfill your properly floating `a`-elements with a `div`'s:

```
div { width: 100%; height: 100%;}
```

Because we have no `position` property of `a`-elements `div`s will fulfill whole page. Lets change `a`-position property to `relative`

```
a {position: relative;}
```

So, now we have this for inner span view:
[image]

```
#center {z-index: 0}
a {z-index: 1;}
```

My final question and the last code change is: what do you want to do in final realization? Your #center container hover will work if no elements above will not intersect with it. If you need section's element hover effect you should place `span`'s inside `#center` container.

Try to describe the goals and I'll try to help you.

```js
$('#div1, #div2, #div3, #div4').click(function(e) {
  $(e.target).toggleClass('fullscreen');
  $(e.target).find('p').fadeToggle(200);
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
}
a {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  float: left;
}
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#div1,
#div2,
#div3,
#div4 {
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-position: center;
  opacity: 0.7;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  position: absolute;
}
#div1 {
  background-image: url("1.jpg");
}
#div2 {
  background-image: url("2.jpg");
}
#div3 {
  background-image: url("3.jpg");
}
#div4 {
  background-image: url("4.jpg");
}
#div1:hover,
#div2:hover,
#div3:hover,
#div4:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
  background-size: 120% 120%;
}
.fullscreen {
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#center {
  position: absolute;
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  z-index: 0;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -150px 0 0 -300px;
  background: #706d6d;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
#center:hover {
  background: #232222;
}
#home {
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 10%;
  text-align: justify;
  margin-top: 5%;
  border-bottom: 3px solid white;
  border-top: 3px solid white;
}
.words {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 25vh;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 300%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">
  <div id="div1">

    <div class="words">
      <span> section 1</span>
      <p id="p1" style="display:none;font-size:50%">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and
        <br/>typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy
        <br/>text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</a>
<a href="#">
  <div id="div2">
    <div class="words">
      <span> section 2</span>
      <p id="p2" style="display:none;font-size:50%">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and
        <br />typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy
        <br />text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
<a href="#">
  <div id="div3">
    <div class="words">
      <span> section 3</span>
      <p id="p3" style="display:none;font-size:50%">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and
        <br />typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy
        <br />text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
<a href="#">
  <div id="div4">
    <div class="words">
      <span> section 4</span>
      <p id="p4" style="display:none;font-size:50%">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and
        <br />typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy
        <br />text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
<div id="center">
  <div id="home">
    <h3 style="text-align:center">HOME</h3>
    <label>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</label>
  </div>
</div>
```